# (Discrod)При запуске бота с помощью .env ,выдаёт ошибку из-за неправильного(хотя правильный) токен

Tags: javascript, бот, discord

Ничего не понимаю,тех. поддержка говорит что смотрит эту проблему,а сам бот не в какую. Пишет что токен неверен. Генерирую уже 500208127 трилионов раз,не в какую опять...

**Сама ошибка:**

```
if (!token || typeof token !== 'string') throw new Error('TOKEN_INVALID');
                                                   ^

Error [TOKEN_INVALID]: An invalid token was provided.
    at Client.login (C:\Users\User\Desktop\X-helper\node_modules\←[4mdiscord.js←[24m\src\client\Client.js:206:52)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\X-helper\index.js:80:8)
←[90m    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1109:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1138:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:989:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)←[39m
←[90m    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47←[39m {
  [←[32mSymbol(code)←[39m]: ←[32m'TOKEN_INVALID'←[39m
```

Comment: А `token` у вас читается? Не пробовали отладкой посмотреть на этой строчке? В этой строке ошибка генерируется только в двух случаях: либо токен пустой, либо не является `string`.

Comment: No, the executor -string is kind of a worker. But the problem is that if the user deleted the message, then in some cases the bot is disabled

Answer (score 0):

```
require("dotenv").config();
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]